# Background color for ionic toggle and range

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

[image: Please refer to this image]

I am using ionic to make a mobile app. I want to add a background to toggle button and range. I used toggle/range-background-dark. It did not work

```
      <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-balanced toggle-background-dark" ng-model="check">
          33
      </ion-toggle> 

      <div class="item range range-balanced range-background-dark">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-sunny-outline"></i>
            <input type="range" name="volume" min="0" max="100" ng-model="RV">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-sunny"></i>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change  toggle button and  range background color using this css

```
.toggle input:checked + .track {
    background-color: #8577b5;
    border-color: #8577b5;
}

.range.range - balanced input::-webkit - slider - thumb: before {
    background: #8577b5;}
.range.range-light input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: # ddd;}
.range.range - stable input::-webkit - slider - thumb: before {
    background: #b2b2b2;
}
.range.range - positive input::-webkit - slider - thumb: before {
    background: #4a87ee; }
.range.range-calm input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #43cee6;
}
.range.range - assertive input::-webkit - slider - thumb: before {
    background: #ef4e3a;
}
.range.range - energized input::-webkit - slider - thumb: before {
    background: #f0b840;
}
.range.range - royal input::-webkit - slider - thumb: before {
    background: #8a6de9; }
.range.range-dark input::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
    background: #444;
}
```

Comment: @S.Yadav were you able to figure it out for Ionic 3?

Comment: Yes, but not remember the steps, as did in long back.

Answer (score 2):

For ion-toggle in Ionic 4 use following to change the background of the toggle when it is checked:

```
ion-toggle {
    --background-checked: var(--ion-color-blue);
}
```

For more information, please visit https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toggle#css-custom-properties